# Is there any way to programatically get the activity name in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have 100+ activities in my Android Studio project. I need to find and replace them with their activity name. For example, my 100+ activities have the same code  as this

```
String activityName = "Example.this";
```

And now I need to search for and replace the `Example` part with their activity name.

For ActivityOne I need to achieve this

```
String activityName = "ActvitiyOne.this";
```

For ActivityTwo I need this

```
String activityName = "ActvitiyTwo.this";
```

I can replace all of them with one word by using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R`.

But is there any way to achieve the above or do I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace them all with `ClassUtils.getSimpleName(this)` or `getClass().getSimpleName()`

```
String activityName = ClassUtils.getSimpleName(this);
 or 
String activityName = getClass().getSimpleName();
```